# Can using a middle layer as an API bypass CORS?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cors, httprequest

I am developing an application using ReactJS, that communicates with another Enterprise application (Oracle Hyperion) using a rest API provided by Hyperion. The problem is that this API is not officially supported, and does not support CORS. I tried finding a solution to this problem with no success.

While trying to solve another problem, I created a Python Flask application, and made all communication between the ReactJS app and Hyperion Rest API pass through it. Somehow, this made the CORS error that was happening disappear. I used the following import and function in the Flask app

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

CORS(app)
```

The ReactJS application now communicates with the Flask app only using Axios, and all requests are successful without the need for allow CORS plugins.

**The question is**: I now need to know how this is possible, because I have an order to avoid using Python for different reasons. I want to know how the problem was solved in order to make sure it doesn't reappear when I rewrite this part using another language or eliminate it even. Does using an API in the middle solve the CORS issue or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cors headers sent by the server are verified by the client, so it's the client which enforces cors. There are browser-plugins to disable cors but this is not advisable for security reasons. 
The usual way of dealing with this is using a reverse proxy and add the relevant HTTP Access-Control response headers to the responses.
So, you can avoid using python by using a reverse proxy (eg nginx/apache).
The api has nothing to do with it, actually in your case you are using flask as a reverse proxy which adds the cors headers. You can debug this by using your browser developer tools.

Comment: Saying using Flask as a reverse proxy, do you mean like this?
response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); (Java code)
And by saying the client is enforcing, do you mean the browser?

Comment: I don't suggest to use flask as a reverse proxy if it's only for cors, better use an app designed to do that (apache/nginx), but in this case it seems you are using flask as a reverse proxy. And by the client I mean the browser yes. Also, using "*" exposes you to potential security issues, you should use the referer url host.

Comment: Do you have any guides or resources on how to use apache as a reverse proxy to add the headers to the response? Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit out of scope for this question, but you can try this site for the cors configuration : https://enable-cors.org/server.html , eg. https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html .  Reverse proxy configuration is described here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ . Check that you can reach the api directly first, then add the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers .

Comment: are you sure using apache as a reverse proxy works in my case? What I understood from the links you added is that it's adding headers to outgoing response from apache not incoming ones like I need.

Comment: I think you should compare header per header and packet per packet to figure out why your setup isnt working... you can also add headers with apache for requests proxied to your flask app but I really dont think you need that. Maybe try with burp proxy to manually modify the headers.

Answer (score 0):

My code to slice through CORS

import requests

```
proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
url = 'Endpoint URL you want yo post to'
datas= {'data1': 'daVal1', 'data2': 'daVal2'}
headers = {'x-requested-with':'root_URL_Of_Endpoint', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj, headers=headers)

print(x.text)
```

ENJOY!